# Python nested dictionaries of dataframes convert to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, recursion

I'm struggling trying to write portable code for a problem that I"m having.  I have a large set of data, structured as nested dictionaries, and at the "bottom" level of said nests (not necessarily the same number of levels) I have Pandas DataFrames. I simply want to traverse through the enter nested dictionary and convert all Pandas DataFrames to json and return the same structure that was input.  Below is a sample code of what I've tried so far.

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [-1,-2,-3,-4]
c = [0,1,-1,0]
d = [1,1,1,-1]

names = ['one','two','three','four']
columns=[f"col_{name}" for name in names]
index=[f"ind_{name}" for name in names]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d], columns=columns, index=index)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([b,c,d,a], columns=columns, index=index)
df_3 = pd.DataFrame([c,d,a,b], columns=columns, index=index)
df_4 = pd.DataFrame([d,a,b,c], columns=columns, index=index)
df_5 = pd.DataFrame([a,a,d,c], columns=columns, index=index)

x={
    'a': {
        'a1': df_1,
        'a2': df_2,
    },
    'b': {
        'b1': df_3,
    },
    'c': {
        'c1': {
            'c11': df_4,
        }
    },
    'd': df_5
}

def nested_dicts(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, pd.DataFrame):
            return {k: v.T.to_json()}
        else:
            return nested_dicts(v)

d = nested_dicts(x)
for k in d.keys():
    print(k)
    print()
```

I've tried this as many ways as I can think, but this is the simplest description of my problem.  I need to be able to pass this to a frontend web service, which is why I need to convert the DataFrames to json, but I want to keep the hierarchical structure, just with df_1,...,df_5 converted to their json values.

If the "best" way is to use a generator, or if there's something I'm not seeing (my brain is kind of fried right now) I'm all ears.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check Ur recurrsion

Comment: ??? Not helping with my fried brain.  If v is a DataFrame, I convert it to json and return the result.  Otherwise I pass said v down to check again.  If you can point me to a related link I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: About to go to bed so I'm not going to log in to my computer to check right now, but I imagine returning {k: nested_dicts(v)} would do the trick. Will check in the morning

Comment: Why is the bottom of the nested structure Pandas DataFrames? What is this all supposed to represent, conceptually? I think there should be easier structures for the same intent.

Comment: @smci there very well may be, but this is a work related problem and this is the structure that I'm being given unfortunately

Comment: Not really sure what the downvoting is for.  I tried searching for quite a while to find something that works, as well as trying every way I could think of, and at the end of that I decided to seek help here.  Is that not what SO is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to consider.

1. Recursion method. Read it carefully. The way you implemented is wrong.
2. Its better to deepcopy the original dict until and unless you absolutely want to modify the original one.

Here is the solution that I think should work.

```
import copy
import pandas as pd

def nested_dicts(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, pd.DataFrame):
            d[k] = v.T.to_json()
        else:
            d[k] = nested_dicts(v)
    return d

d = nested_dicts(copy.deepcopy(x))   # Deepcopy to keep x intact
```

Cheers!

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to explain it @MaNKuR  The biggest problem I found myself running into is that the structure wasn't being preserved.  This was one of those _relatively_ simple things that I should have figured out but just needed another set of eyes to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad it helped u :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is to access each dictionary recursively, and if the data type of any of the data matches what you want, then you have it

```
def iterdict(d):
    pandas = pd
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            iterdict(v)
        else:
            if type(v) == pandas.core.frame.DataFrame:
                print("\nthis is pandas !\n\n" , v)


iterdict(x) 

>> 

this is pandas !

            col_one  col_two  col_three  col_four
ind_one          1        2          3         4
ind_two         -1       -2         -3        -4
ind_three        0        1         -1         0
ind_four         1        1          1        -1

this is pandas !

            col_one  col_two  col_three  col_four
ind_one         -1       -2         -3        -4
ind_two          0        1         -1         0
ind_three        1        1          1        -1
ind_four         1        2          3         4

this is pandas !

            col_one  col_two  col_three  col_four
ind_one          0        1         -1         0
ind_two          1        1          1        -1
ind_three        1        2          3         4
ind_four        -1       -2         -3        -4

this is pandas !

            col_one  col_two  col_three  col_four
ind_one          1        1          1        -1
ind_two          1        2          3         4
ind_three       -1       -2         -3        -4
ind_four         0        1         -1         0

this is pandas !

            col_one  col_two  col_three  col_four
ind_one          1        2          3         4
ind_two          1        2          3         4
ind_three        1        1          1        -1
ind_four         0        1         -1         0
```

I added the `pandas = pd`because otherwise type `'pandas'` will not be recognized